# How to get nested loop value using map function in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**How to get TC id value and using map function in react js**

Here's my code json

```
[
    {
        "Results": {
            "TC": [
                {
                   "id": 1
                 },
                 {
                   "id": 2
                 },
                 {
                   "id": 3
                 }
            ]
        }
   }
]
```

Here's my React Code:

```
import PostData from './result_log.json';

{PostData.map((PostDetail, index) => {
    return <h1>{PostDetail.Results.TC.length}</h1>
})}
```

Comment: Do you to create a separate `h1` tag for each id?

Comment: yes i need to create h1 tag for each id

Comment: @GurumoorthyDhanabal Does my answer fullfill your needs ?

Comment: @Hurobaki I was tired but it's not working for me. can you provide me any jsfiddle link for this example

Comment: I've provided you a jsfiddle link inside my answer

Comment: @Hurobaki Thank you for providing. I will try this and update you

Comment: @GurumoorthyDhanabal Did it works ?

Comment: @Hurobaki Yes it's working properly thank you now only finished and then i have one doubt how to filters in map function any idea about that

Comment: Yes you can use the filter() method. What do you want to filter here ?

Comment: Before that i have problem in this coding. Newly i added one extra in json like Head:{ "HeadCon": "One" } inside TC before or after id and i add one more h1 tag in return map function but it's not working what's the problem?

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/omks3yz9/3/) my link please check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to create a `h1` balise tag for each id inside your `TC` array in your json code.

```
import PostData from './result_log.json';

const getAllIds = () => {
  const idsArray = PostData.map(item => {
    return item.Results.TC.map(it => <h1>{it.id}</h1>)
  }.reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr], [])

  return idsArray
}

getAllIds()
```

I have flattened the first map result so you have only one array containing every id key value of your json code.

https://jsfiddle.net/v5r8oyds/